# I cant figure out what this form "action" means

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Could someone explain what method or how a form thats using this code works?

```
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='gform_ajax_frame_1' id='gform_1' 
 action='/contact-us/#gf_1'>
</form>
```

I'm trying to learn more about forms, and right now I'm trying to build a multipart form like one of my friends did.

I'm used to forms saying `action="contact.php"` but this one says `action="/contact_us/#gf_1"`. What does it mean?

Comment: Basically it just says that *something* located at `<host>/contact-us/` is supposed to handle a [`POST` request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In forms

**Action refers**

to Where to send the form-data when the form is submitted

**and methods refers to**

The method attribute specifies how to send form-data (the form-data is sent to the page specified in the action attribute).

The form-data can be sent as URL variables (with method="get") or as HTTP post transaction (with method="post").

Notes on GET:

> Appends form-data into the URL in name/value pairs The length of a URL
>   is limited (about 3000 characters) Never use GET to send sensitive
>   data! (will be visible in the URL) Useful for form submissions where a
>   user want to bookmark the result GET is better for non-secure data,
>   like query strings in Google

Notes on POST:

> Appends form-data inside the body of the HTTP request (data is not
>   shown is in URL) Has no size limitations Form submissions with POST
>   cannot be bookmarked

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

Comment: Eugh. Typical W3Schools, missing [the most important difference between POST and GET](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1).

Comment: @Quentin Which, sadly, a lot of people seem to ignore when asking questions regarding the "confirm re-submit" prompt :-/ Another must-read is [URIs, Addressability, and the use of HTTP GET and POST](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html).

Comment: @Quentin could I maybe email you the whole form that I'm trying to understand and maybe you have some advice?

Comment: @Abel: better to ask specific questions on Stack Overflow like you’ve done here: then the answers are shared with the rest of the world.

Answer (score 2):

It's a URI (although one with a fragment identifier in it, which is unusual for a form action).

Sometimes a URI lets you infer what technologies the server will use to generate the response for it. This isn't one of those URIs.

It might use PHP. It might not. There are certainly plenty of technologies that could be used ([Perl](http://www.perl.org/), [Python](http://python.org/), [JavaScript](http://nodejs.org/), [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/), [Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/), [.NET](http://www.asp.net/), etc, etc, etc). There is no way to tell which *is* being used from that HTML.

The technologies involved should only matter to the people who have the access to change them though, and those people can look on the server to see how the URI would be handled.

Since all of them *can* handle everything that a contact form would need on the server, knowing what that particular example uses wouldn't provide any insight into building your own.

Comment: I'd use Perl with [PSGI](http://plackperl.org/) and either [Web::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/Web::Simple), [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/) or [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/) … but it is a somewhat personal preference (which has to be tempered by the options presented by your web hosting service and your ability to move to a different hosting service).

Answer (score 2):

`<form action="">` is like `<a href="">` - it specifies the URL that the browser will request when the form is submitted.

The URL for both `action` and `href` can be relative or absolute. `contact.php` is relative to the current page, so when a form with that action is submitted, the browser will take the current page’s URL, remove everything after the last `/`, append `contact.php`, and submit the form to that URL. E.g.

- `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266788/contact.php`

In contrast, `/contact-us/#gf_1` starts with a `/`, so it’s relative to the current *domain*. In this case, the browser will take the domain of the current page, append `/contactus/#gf_1` to that, and submit the form there. E.g.

- `http://stackoverflow.com/contact-us/#gf_1`

In URLs, the hash (`#`) character starts the [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). This refers to an anchor point on the page, indicated in the HTML by either a named anchor tag (e.g. `<a name="gf_1"></a>`) or an id attribute on any tag (e.g. `<p id="gf_1"></p>`).

By convention, when a browser goes to a URL with a fragment identifier, it will scroll the anchor point referred to by that fragment identifier into view when the page loads.

The fragment identifier is *not* sent to the server, so by itself it won’t have any effect on a form submission. However, JavaScript running on the page can look at the fragment identifier, and could send an AJAX request to the server based on it.

Comment: D. Waithe then the #gf_1 is the file which specifies where the form information is sent to?

Comment: @Abel: ah, no. I shall update the answer to explain that bit too.

Comment: Just saw that, thank you very much.. I realize that this is a bit too much for me but I'm starting to understand. Just one thing though. "AJAX sends a request to server" I dont really get that? to what does it send request?

Comment: @Abel: it's not too much for you, it's just stuff you don't understand yet. "AJAX sends a request to server" - I didn't say that. What I said was that although the fragment identifier doesn't get sent to the server, and so won't on its own affect the form submission, the page that the server returns *could* have JavaScript running on it, and that JavaScript *could* look at the value of the fragment identifier, and *could* then send an AJAX request to the server based on the value of the fragment identifier.

Comment: I just bought the whole form with all the files that comes with.. If u give me you email I can send it to you and maybe you could help out? If its working its much easier for me to understand. Are you willing? or you could send me an email on mediabyranab@gmail.com I really need your help..

Comment: @Abel: I'm afraid I don't have the time to offer one-to-one programming assistance. If you've got further questions about the code you're trying to work with though, feel free to post them here (and even link to them in comments on our answers), so that the world can get the benefit of the answers.